# Abort Called when using Strings to Read Album Information from a file

Tags: c++, string, abort

abort has been called when I run my code, although it builds successfully. Can anyone give me tips to how to make my code better to run so that abort is not called? 
It references two text files, but here is my code thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("Album Name1.txt");
    string album_name; 
    string artist = album_name.substr(0, album_name.find("-"));
    cout << "Artist : " << artist << endl;
    string album = album_name.substr(album_name.find("-"), album_name.rfind("-"));
    cout << " Album Title: " << album << endl;
    string song = album_name.substr(album_name.length(), album_name.rfind("-"));
    cout << " Song Title : " << song << endl;
    string time = album_name.substr(album_name.find("2"), (album_name.find("2")));
    string minutes = time.substr(0, 0);
    string seconds = time.substr(1, 2);
    string minutes_seconds = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    cout << "Run Time: " << minutes_seconds << endl;
    cout << "Copyright (c) Bruce Springsteen, 1984";
    fin.close();
    fin.clear();
    ifstream ifin("Album Name2.txt");
    string album2_name;
    string artist2 = album2_name.substr(0, album2_name.find("-"));
    cout << "Artist : " << artist2 << endl;
    string album2 = album2_name.substr(album2_name.find("-"), album2_name.rfind("-"));
    cout << " Album Title: " << album2 << endl;
    string song2 = album2_name.substr(album2_name.length(), album2_name.rfind("-"));
    cout << " Song Title : " << song2 << endl;
    string time2 = album2_name.substr(album2_name.find("2"), (album2_name.find("2")));
    string minutes2 = time2.substr(0, 0);
    string seconds2 = time2.substr(1, 2);
    string minutes_seconds2 = minutes2 + ":" + seconds2;
    cout << "Run Time: " << minutes_seconds2 << endl;
    cout << "Copyright (c) Maroon 5, 2004";
    ifin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't dump an entire code listing with no context. Edit your code down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking for help.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could tell us what the program is supposed to do when it works correctly. Also, please include an example of the how the input files are structured. Finally, just by looking at your code it doesn't look like the `ifstreams` are being used at all. Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ for tips

Comment: It is supposed to read in album details about an artist from a text file and then list them in cout.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set or read the album name, so the whole algorithm is processing an empty string.

Assuming you meant to read the album name from the input file, you should have written:

```
ifstream fin("Album Name1.txt");
string album_name; 
std::getline(fin,album_name);
```